# Is it possible to run wp_kses on all posts?

Tags: posts, wp-kses

For security purposes, we're mostly using the wordpress json api to display our posts/categories and we went to remove any malicious tags.
I'm a bit unfamiliar with WP development... but what I'm trying to achieve is basically:

1. Query all current posts
2. Run `wp_kses` on all the post's content?

What I'm trying so far in `functions.php`

```php
  $post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
  $post_query = new WP_Query($post_args);

  while( $post_query->have_posts()): $post_query->the_post();
    // wp_kses the content here???
  endwhile;
```

I'm not entirely sure where go from here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @vancoder For security purposes. We're mostly using the wordpress json api to display our posts and we went to remove any malicious tags as it gets sent through the api. I'll update my question with the intent.

Comment: Can you use `the_content` filter hook?

Comment: Why would your posts contain malicious tags? If you’ve been compromised this isn’t a sufficient fix.

Answer (score 1):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66561796/1875965
and using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

use either `wp_kses_post` or `wp_kses`

if using `wp_kses`, you can specify an allow list of html tags, or use `wp_kses( $content, 'post')` for the default post html filtering

once in your loop, you'd have access to `$post` so you can do

```
while( $post_query->have_posts()): $post_query->the_post();
    $clear_post = wp_kses( $post->content, $allowed_html );
    wp_reset_postdata(); //because we're using the_post

    // do stuff with cleared post content.

endwhile;
```

though you might want to consider a different loop, like

```
$all_posts = $post_query->get_posts();
foreach( $all_posts as $filter_post) {
 $clear_post = wp_kses_post( $filter_post->post_content );
  // do stuff with cleared post content.
}
```

the above specifically uses the string in `post_content`, but there are possibly other values (`post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_name` (slug), meta data, custom fields) you'd want to sanitise

other related developer docs
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/